# Eth0 missing Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Envy

Tags: networking, ethernet

I've seen a bunch of questions regarding this, and I've tried a bunch of the solutions, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere ...

`ifconfig -a` shows:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2058  bytes 218199 (218.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2058  bytes 218199 (218.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::311a:4c2d:f1bc:d430  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:8b:fd:f5:52:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18770  bytes 15450715 (15.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12143  bytes 2037808 (2.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Wireless is running fine ... I'm running on an HP Envy verion:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried. If you've tried 'a bunch' there's a decent probability we'll be tossing some of that bunch right back at you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you do not see eth0 in the ifconfig output, at all, indicates that the wired ethernet device is unprovisioned. Perhaps there was a driver load error, due to an unforeseen condition. Try examination of the kernel log for problems with ethernet driver loading. The command below might be revealing:

dmesg | grep -i eth0